# DLL not found on certain machine with luajit FFI

Tags: dll, lua, ffi, love2d, luajit

I have built [Game Music Emu](https://bitbucket.org/mpyne/game-music-emu/wiki/Home) from source to use with Love2d. (Note: I am not very familiar with C/C++.)

In lua I load the dll with [FFI](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html) and on *my* computer it works great, but when I sent my friend the app for testing, his machine doesn't recognize the DLL.

I sent him the love2d binaries with the `libgme` DLL included to make sure he didn't just misplace the DLL file. So what he is running is the *exact* same thing I am running.

My code looks like this:

```
ffi.cdef[[ ... ]]
local gme = ffi.load("libgme")
```

This is the exact error my friend gets:

```
lovegme.lua:4: cannot load module 'libgme.dll': The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Could be a 32bit/64bit mismatch, or just a problem with the directory structure. Also what OS are both of you using?

Comment: We are both using Windows 10 on 64 bit machines. libgme.dll and love.exe are both definitely 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how `libgme` is compiled you may have some dependencies that are satisfied on your computer (for example, mingw libraries), but not satisfied on the other computer.

I'd try several things: (1) use the full filename in the `load` command, (2) use "profile" mode in [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check what is failing during DLL load, or (3) use the same dependency walker on your machine to see what other DLLs libgme may depend upon and include those in your package/installation as well.

Comment: Apparently the issue was that libgme depended on libstdc++. I added `-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` to the compilation flags, and now it works. Thanks.